# Non-sense error Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: c++, ios, ld

I've built a 32 bit library that is a requirement to my project. Here's its lipo info:

```
LP:lib hcabral$ lipo -info Release-iphoneos/librmservices_iphone.a  
input file Release-iphoneos/librmservices_iphone.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: Release-iphoneos/librmservices_iphone.a is architecture: armv7
```

I link the library in my project, it shows up in "Link Binary with binaries", etc., and yet I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"std::_List_node_base::hook(std::_List_node_base*)", referenced from:
  xpath::YaccParser::getObjectPointer(uft::Value*&, bool) in librmservices_iphone.a(xpath_yacc.o)
  xpath::YaccParser::performLexicalAnalysis(uft::Value*&) in librmservices_iphone.a(xpath_yacc.o)
"std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)", referenced from:
  xpath::Context::removeDynamicContext(uft::Value const&) in librmservices_iphone.a(xpath_context.o)
"_kCFProxyPasswordKey", referenced from:
  DLProxySettingsController::getSystemProxySettings() in librmservices_iphone.a(DLProxySettingsController.o)
"_kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPProxy", referenced from:
(...)
```

All the projects I limited to armv7 and no solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Link your executable with a C++ compiler not with a C compiler. The missing symbol looks like one from the standard C++ library.

Comment: Dietmar, by the time I read this I had added the libstdc++ link, but there were some others. I will post a complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have a project A that is pure Objective-C, but it depends on a Project B that is C/C++ and Objective-C, and happens to be 32-bit code only.

Up until Mavericks and Xcode 5.1.1, I built Project B for all platforms (Release and Debug for iOS and i386) in order to debug, run tests and eventually deploy. Project B has its own set of linker flags and options that make it very special.

In project A, I would link the binaries of Project B (libProjectB.a) and it has always worked.

However, during this last iteration, Project A build process complained about missing symbols for armv7, which confused me, because project B is compiled ONLY in armv7 and i386.

The only way I manage to remove 30+ linking errors, was by linking the following frameworks:

```
libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib
CoreText.framework
CFNetwork.framework
Foundation.framework
```

I hope these don't look like random frameworks to you, but I found out by adding one by one, based on the type of linking error. For example, I added the **CFNetwork** only after opening the C++ code and noticing that the symbols would be part of it.

Anyway, again, I don't know why it happened yet, but it happened by using Yosemite and Xcode 6.1. Hope this can shed a light on someone.